# SSRS report hang in loading

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have accidentally deleted a data source from the SSRS Report Server.  After I have re-created the data source and have deployed all the reports again to the report server (I have deleted all reports and re-deployed them), all the reports hang in "Loading ...".  Also, I found the following error message in the SSRS log file:

> Unhandled exception:
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandlerInputException: Missing URL
>   parameter: IterationId    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HandlerOperation.GetAndEnsureParam(NameValueCollection
>   urlQuery, String paramName)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportImageOperation.PerformOperation(NameValueCollection
>   urlQuery, HttpResponse response)    at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Anyone have any idea what it means and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Its clear from the error message that your URL is missing a parameter named `IterationId`.

You might want to refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993721/reportviewer-ie-11) where it suggests concatenating `&IterationId=0` at the end of the URL.

What that actually does is adding `&IterationID=0` to the end of the URL

```
HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(u.PathAndQuery + "&IterationId=0");
```