# Report Viewer control not showing report from SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm using MS Report Viewer 10 in VS 2013; the project is being upgraded from VS 2010.  I have worked through a series of issues relating to Report Viewer, and have the control itself up and running.  I have a number of reports in SSRS, and I have confirmed that the reports themselves work properly.

I have a Web Forms ASPX page for data input.  It passes data via JSON to a popup ASPX page that contains the Report Viewer control.

I am running IIS Express 7, SQL Server 2008 R2 (v10.50), and a current target framework of .NET Framework 4.5.

Report Viewer does not return any report -- no error message, no report layout missing data, and certainly no complete report.  When I run the same report with the same inputs through VS, the report preview shows the results I expect.

`ProcessingMode` is set to `Remote` and `ReportServerCredentials` is `null`.  I researched what this means, and it means that Report Viewer should connect to SSRS with the current network credentials, namely the current user.  I confirmed that the current user correctly matches my current login; I can connect to SSRS and SQL Server using Windows authentication properly.

ReportViewer doesn't create in the web form designer, so I can't set any properties on it at design time.

So I suspect my issue is a matter of authentication at run time.  I am out of ideas on how to investiagte and resolve this.

The control code on the page:

```
    <ssrs:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Width="100%"
        Height="690" ShowParameterPrompts="false" AsyncRendering="false"/>
```

The SSRS log contains the following entries after I attempt to run the report:

```
library!ReportServer_0-3!1dc8!(datetime): i INFO: RenderForNewSession('(report)')
webserver!ReportServer_0-3!1dc8!(datetime, 1 second later): i INFO: Processed report. Report='(report)', Stream=''
```

The legacy project used MS Report Viewer 9.  It ran just fine.  The only changes I see in `web.config` relate to the later version and a change from IIS 6 to IIS 7.

Since it came up in comments, here's the relevant line from web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

My Report Viewer window:
[image: Report Viewer blank window]

---

ETA 24 Nov: I eventually got an entry in the application log:  `HttpHandlerInputException, Missing URL parameter: IterationId`.  This issue has been discussed at [another STOF Q&A.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21993721/2615836)

Comment: does your report show the header (where the filters and Show Report button appears)?

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales: Report Viewer's header does appear -- the bar with the page selection (showing page 1 of 2, which is correct), Find|Next, save, and refresh.  All controls on the header are disabled.

Comment: Can you please inspect the area below of report's header? Check if there's a hidden error message like: The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in the application's web.config file -or- Could not load type 'Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd'

Comment: When I view the HTML source, I see the "has not been registered" error message in a `<div>` element with an ID of `ReportViewer_HttpHandlerMissingErrorMessage`.  In fact, I saw that yesterday, and confirmed that the requested line already exists in the `system.webserver/handlers` node of web.config -- character for character, in fact, with the same order of fields.

Comment: Got it, so please check if this "<add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false" />" have been added to <httpHandlers> and <system.webServer><handlers>. Hope it helps.

Comment: I just updated my post with the line from sys.webServer/handlers.  I had had issues with httpHandlers; I'll restore that and give it a try.

Comment: Oh.  Why are you suggesting version 8?

Comment: Re-enabling the `system.web/httpHandlers` node with the entry for ReportViewer caused HTTP error 500.

Comment: I do remember that I should add a handler on IIS 7, check this out: http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/why-reportviewer-control-not-working-on-iis-7/

Comment: Another Stack Overflow Q&A led me to that post.  I previously added the managed handler as the article describes.  I still can't see my reports while debugging locally.  So good suggestion; I've already done that.

Comment: Please add the name attribute to your web.config add node (<add name="ReportViewerWebControl" path="Reserved...), it must match with the name you set on IIS handler mapping.

Comment: The name in the node already matches the name in the handler mapping.  I corrected the managed handler to use version 10; this made no difference.

Comment: OK, let's check IIS. Are you under Default Web Site node? If so, please check if there's that handler mapping already, in that case your application must inherit that handler. Now, if you are on a different web site, please make sure your Path's file handler is File or Folder. Also check its Request Restrictions, Access tab must have Script option selected.

Comment: I'm not under Default Web Site.  I checked Request Restrictions; the Access is correct, and I changed the Mapping to File or Folder.  No effect.  Out of curiosity, I right-clicked on Handler Mapping, brought up Basic Settings, and clicked on Test Settings.  Pass-through authentication rejected my connection.  I'll explore this, as it might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by @CodeswithHammer I'm adding this reference to another thread for  just to save people some time searching for it.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22000827/1807669

Comment: For completeness:  The answer here is to update `Global.asax` and add the `IterationId` to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

When you update version of the SSRS control in your app and web.config you also need to add a new handler for it in IIS. If you had one in your mappings previously remove it and add a new one.

1. Open IIS manager and select your application Under IIS section
2. Double click on Handler Mappings icon On the Action pane on your
3. Right click Add Managed Handler
4. When the dialog opens enter the following:

   **Request path**: Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd

   **Type**: Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler

   **Name**: Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd
5. Cick OK

Also makesure your server, credentials and path to your report are correct.

```
var serverReport = this.ReportViewer1.ServerReport;
serverReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials(userName, password, "yourDomain.com");
serverReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("your report server");
serverReport.ReportPath = "yourReportName";
serverReport.Refresh();
```

And in your aspx:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
```

Comment: I already had the mapping with the correct `Request path` and `Type`.  I renamed it as you suggested.  It made no difference.

Comment: That's what I was saying, if it's there already completely remove it and then re-add it.

Comment: Mapping dropped and readded.  Trying... and the report window is still blank.  (See screen shot that I added to my question.)

Comment: Ok well you have the report viewer now so that appears to be working. Now it's just a matter of it loading the report. Are you passing it the right server info and credentials?

Comment: I am pretty sure I'm passing the right server info and credentials.  Please tell me how to check what credentials the server receives.

Comment: The easiest way to do that is take the full report path and paste it in the browser. You will be prompted for your credentials. If they do not work then you will need to get the right login info from whoever has control of the report server. The server will receive what you send it so there is no need to check what it is getting, only that you are sending the correct login info.

Comment: Huh.  When I went to my report page (`Report.aspx`, very original) directly in the browser and passed the report name, I was not prompted for any credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Below is code snippet using which i am using to bind ReportViewer with SSRS report

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerNetworkCredentials("ReportServerUsername", "ReportServerPassword", "");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://mymachinename//ReportServer");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/MyReports/TestReport1";
```

Here ReportServerUrl  is path of SQL Report Server(SSRS) configured in my machine and in ReportPath "MyReports" is folder in SQL Report Server in which i have Report named TestReport1

Comment: Is that in your code-behind file?  My project doesn't call Report Viewer from code-behind.  I've been trying to trace down where it gets called.