# Internet Explorer 11(IE11) and reportviewer

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008, report-viewer2012

I am facing a strange problem, due to microsoft update, I can not see the report on IE11, I am using asp.net and reportviewer(ver.1.0.2243.16835), if anybody has resolution to this problem, please share, 
Thanks.

under debugger, it says permission denied

[image]

Comment: Are there any messages or errors in F12 developer tools console?

Comment: devlin, I have attached the pic

Comment: And have you tried Compatibility mode ?  And have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993721/reportviewer-ie-11) ?

Comment: yes I tried that.